# How to disable downloading packages from the internet in Debian, and instead let it ask me to insert DVDs?

Tags: debian, package-management, software-updates

Here is my problem. I have downloaded all the 14 DVD images and burned them to disks, because I like it that way. I don't want updates. And I don't want the latest packages.

I want packages from the DVDs even if I have good net bandwidth. But if I install Debian with connection to the internet, later on in my apt sources list I can see that all my scanned DVD images are commented out!

And even more, if I ran

```
apt-cache search
```

for a package, it does not find my wanted programs even though during setup I have inserted and scanned all of my DVDs!

There is another bug during setup. It asks me if I wanted to scan another disk, and when I say `Yes`, it does not eject my DVD!!

I was able to circumvent this part, but still, very annoying!

**Update**

Images I have:

```
b39b85a222865b6808b831d3aeb53007  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
f095dcb4076f0f3baa383baa52681673  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-10.iso
24ca2e54bafaec03a1c534187d721076  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-11.iso
4f9a93dead737784737088a199070ce4  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-12.iso
73202eeeacc853544494930378a21de1  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-13.iso
68a379c21c790cdd51cddbe89350d8a0  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-14.iso
3f666fa9c8565e8e0589572225ca4ecb  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso
56863b5bab38ae0b2845af20ac985d45  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso
29e9e5f7a7dd87c6e971f625423d0522  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-4.iso
0ba41b5c02eb8f719039ac7080191217  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-5.iso
f9a995d3f9cef90fd2464ae5aaf3fa5d  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-6.iso
5ce0d968346b56a757f1efad671cfae2  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-7.iso
815478043cea051f1c27ed026856a903  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-8.iso
055b3bf21f2441ac118848a018bd0de8  debian-9.9.0-amd64-DVD-9.iso
```

Comment: So you don’t mind using an Internet-connected system without any security updates?

Comment: I do not mind, updates only mess up things. And it is my home pc, does not have any public IP. I am a Windows user too where I have disabled all updates as well.

Comment: It's been a while since I re-installed but I thought there was an option to [not] download updates while installing.  Can you confirm which relevant options you chose during installation?

Comment: Could you clarify which 14 DVD images you downloaded? All the arch-specific images, or [the 14 source DVD images](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/source/iso-dvd/), or [the 16 Jigdo images](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-dvd/)?

Comment: I downloaded the amd64 specific images (see update in the original question). About the steps, now I am going to repeat the whole process (reinstall) and take notes. Brb.

Comment: I see in the 10 version there is also update images. Why can't the debian team do a release without making changes afterwards. Debian is not what it was used to be.

Comment: Because the Debian team isn't criminally irresponsible, so they understand the basic principles of security. Not providing updates would make Debian useless for anything except being used as a toy. You can't allow security holes to be unpatched in a a professional system. Even on a personal one it is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

During installation, at least for Debian 10 (and IIRC in earlier releases too), you’ll be asked whether to configure a network mirror:

[image: Screenshot of the “Configure the package manager” screen in the Debian installer]

Answering “No” at this point will result in a system configured to retrieve packages from the CD-ROMs or DVD-ROMs you’ve scanned, and from the security mirror.

Once installation is complete and you’ve booted into your new system, you should find that `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains a line starting with `deb cdrom:`, and lines pointing to `security.debian.org`. To disable updates, remove the latter, or comment them out.

You don’t need to scan all your DVDs during installation; you can scan them later with `apt-cdrom add`.

Note that by doing this you won’t get security updates either. If you don’t use *any* network-connected software, and make sure that your system doesn’t for you, then that won’t be an issue. (You also won’t get any fixes for severe bugs.)

Comment: Thank you. I think, the issue either is if I am connected to the internet I am not asked if I want to use a mirror, or either the problem is that I scanned all of the DVDs. Last time I reinstalled but I unplugged the network cable and I only scanned 3 dvds, and afterwards i scanned the rest with apt-cdrom... and it worked as expected... I will do another install either way.